# can i push and call a proc inside a proc?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, callstack, stack-memory

I want to call a proc in another proc . the proc from the inside must be pushed before, the inside proc has ret 4. when i run it my computer stops working is there a way to do this? maybe add another pop? i want the value of color to be changed.

```
proc borders ;the out proc , before calling I pushed offset head
push bp
mov bp,sp
push ax dx di si
        mov di, [bp+4] ; offset of head
        mov si, [di] ; value of head
        sub si, 158
        push offset color
        call random ; the in proc
        mov [di], si
        pop si di dx ax bp
ret 4
endp borders

proc random ;before used I pushed offset color
push bp
mov bp,sp
  push ax bx dx 
  push ds          
  xor  dx, dx      ; The word-sized `DIV` division requires initiating
  mov  ds, dx
  mov  ax, [046Ch] ; read timer counter
  pop  ds
  xor  ax, [cs:bx] ; XOR counter and a WORD from memory
  mov  bx, 2000    ; limit : 0-3998
  div  bx          ; DX:AX / BX -> Remainder in DX is [0,1999]
  shl  dx, 1       
  mov  bx, [bp+4] ; changes the value of food/color depend on use.
  mov [bx], dx
  pop  dx bx ax bp
  ret 4
endp random
```

Comment: Since you only passed 1 argument, the `random` should end with `ret 2`. You did not show it so can't tell if that is the case.

Comment: Also this function seems to be using 1 argument only, so why does it have `ret 4` at the end?

Comment: Re: your title, you of course you can push and call inside a proc, if you do it right and restore the stack properly afterwards.  Those instructions would be pretty useless if they couldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can. A proc can even call itself if you want a recursive function.